# How to get a nested data from different models in django.?

Tags: python, django, models

In my webpage, i need to click on a link that takes me to the list of college names....then by selecting the name it needs to take me to the list of departments available in the particular college..then by choosing a department it needs to take me to the list of available blood groups ...then by choosing a blood group it needs to take me to the list of students available for the particular blood group...!!

these should be linked on a chained manner..!!

how can i do this with the help of models...please give me some suggestions friends..!! iam a learner..!!

## models.py

class CollegeName(models.Model):

```
name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

class Batch(models.Model):

```
batch = models.CharField(max_length=15)
college = models.OneToOneField(CollegeName,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='batches',null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.batch
```

class BloodGroup(models.Model):

```
blood = models.CharField(max_length=50)
batch_of_students = models.OneToOneField(Batch,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='blood_group_list',null=True)
# college = models.ForeignKey(College_name,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='college_name_via_blood_group',null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.blood
```

class AddDonors(models.Model):

```
student_name = models.CharField(max_length = 264)
address = models.CharField(max_length=264)
blood_group = models.ForeignKey(BloodGroup,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='donors',null=True)
mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
date_of_birth = models.DateField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.student_name
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Your question as it currently is sounds like you're basically asking someone to do all the work for you...